# Connecting to Kafka from Spring boot, Error connecting to node [machinname:port] (id: 0 rack: null)

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to publish a message to Kafka using spring boot. I've tried it a few ways, and the one below is the least complicated.

Kafka is on a local VM. The firewall is Status: inactive. I'm running a broker from the terminal.

```
$bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

There is a lot of output from spring, but the error I see is "Error connecting to node il02:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)" and "il02: Name or service not known"

il02 is the VM's machine name. I'm using the actual IP when configurin the producer. What am I doing wrong here?

My Spring main():

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //SpringApplication.run(KafkaTest01Application.class, args);
    Properties kafkaProps = new Properties();
    kafkaProps.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.56.112:9092");
    kafkaProps.put("key.serializer",
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    kafkaProps.put("value.serializer",
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(kafkaProps);


    ProducerRecord<String,String> record = 
            new ProducerRecord<>("quickstart-events", "test", "test01");
    try {
        producer.send(record);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    producer.close();
}
```

And the output to the console.

```
19:08:46.536 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig - ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = -1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.56.112:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-1
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = true
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

19:08:46.731 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
19:08:46.831 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
19:08:46.833 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 3.1.1
19:08:46.835 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId: 97671528ba54a138
19:08:46.835 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka startTimeMs: 1662505726829
19:08:46.835 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Transition from state UNINITIALIZED to INITIALIZING
19:08:46.837 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Kafka producer started
19:08:47.187 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Enqueuing transactional request InitProducerIdRequestData(transactionalId=null, transactionTimeoutMs=2147483647, producerId=-1, producerEpoch=-1)
19:08:47.189 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initialize connection to node 192.168.56.112:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
19:08:47.193 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils - Resolved host 192.168.56.112 as 192.168.56.112
19:08:47.194 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node 192.168.56.112:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) using address /192.168.56.112
19:08:47.206 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
19:08:47.210 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
19:08:47.211 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
19:08:47.233 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending API_VERSIONS request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=0) and timeout 30000 to node -1: ApiVersionsRequestData(clientSoftwareName='apache-kafka-java', clientSoftwareVersion='3.1.1')
19:08:47.275 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received API_VERSIONS response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=0): ApiVersionsResponseData(errorCode=0, apiKeys=[ApiVersion(apiKey=0, minVersion=0, maxVersion=9), ApiVersion(apiKey=1, minVersion=0, maxVersion=13), ApiVersion(apiKey=2, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=3, minVersion=0, maxVersion=12), ApiVersion(apiKey=4, minVersion=0, maxVersion=6), ApiVersion(apiKey=5, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=6, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=7, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=8, minVersion=0, maxVersion=8), ApiVersion(apiKey=9, minVersion=0, maxVersion=8), ApiVersion(apiKey=10, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=11, minVersion=0, maxVersion=9), ApiVersion(apiKey=12, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=13, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=14, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=15, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=16, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=17, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=18, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=19, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=20, minVersion=0, maxVersion=6), ApiVersion(apiKey=21, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=22, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=23, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=24, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=25, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=26, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=27, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=28, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=29, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=30, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=31, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=32, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=33, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=34, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=35, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=36, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=37, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=38, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=39, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=40, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=41, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=42, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=43, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=44, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=45, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=46, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=47, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=48, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=49, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=50, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=51, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=56, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=57, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=60, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=61, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=65, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=66, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=67, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0)], throttleTimeMs=0, supportedFeatures=[], finalizedFeaturesEpoch=0, finalizedFeatures=[])
19:08:47.364 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 has finalized features epoch: 0, finalized features: [], supported features: [], API versions: (Produce(0): 0 to 9 [usable: 9], Fetch(1): 0 to 13 [usable: 13], ListOffsets(2): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], Metadata(3): 0 to 12 [usable: 12], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 to 6 [usable: 5], StopReplica(5): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], ControlledShutdown(7): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 8 [usable: 8], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 8 [usable: 8], FindCoordinator(10): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 9 [usable: 7], Heartbeat(12): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 5 [usable: 4], SyncGroup(14): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], ListGroups(16): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 6 [usable: 6], DeleteRecords(21): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], InitProducerId(22): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], EndTxn(26): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], TxnOffsetCommit(28): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DescribeAcls(29): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], CreateAcls(30): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DeleteAcls(31): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AlterConfigs(33): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeLogDirs(35): 0 to 3 [usable: 2], SaslAuthenticate(36): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], CreatePartitions(37): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateDelegationToken(38): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], RenewDelegationToken(39): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ExpireDelegationToken(40): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeDelegationToken(41): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DeleteGroups(42): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ElectLeaders(43): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], IncrementalAlterConfigs(44): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterPartitionReassignments(45): 0 [usable: 0], ListPartitionReassignments(46): 0 [usable: 0], OffsetDelete(47): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeClientQuotas(48): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterClientQuotas(49): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeUserScramCredentials(50): 0 [usable: 0], AlterUserScramCredentials(51): 0 [usable: 0], AlterIsr(56): 0 to 1 [usable: 0], UpdateFeatures(57): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeCluster(60): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeProducers(61): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeTransactions(65): 0 [usable: 0], ListTransactions(66): 0 [usable: 0], AllocateProducerIds(67): 0 [usable: 0]).
19:08:47.366 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending metadata request MetadataRequestData(topics=[MetadataRequestTopic(topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, name='quickstart-events')], allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false) to node 192.168.56.112:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
19:08:47.368 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending METADATA request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=12, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=1) and timeout 30000 to node -1: MetadataRequestData(topics=[MetadataRequestTopic(topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, name='quickstart-events')], allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false)
19:08:47.372 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending transactional request InitProducerIdRequestData(transactionalId=null, transactionTimeoutMs=2147483647, producerId=-1, producerEpoch=-1) to node 192.168.56.112:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) with correlation ID 2
19:08:47.372 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending INIT_PRODUCER_ID request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=INIT_PRODUCER_ID, apiVersion=4, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=2) and timeout 30000 to node -1: InitProducerIdRequestData(transactionalId=null, transactionTimeoutMs=2147483647, producerId=-1, producerEpoch=-1)
19:08:47.376 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received METADATA response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=12, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=1): MetadataResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, brokers=[MetadataResponseBroker(nodeId=0, host='il02', port=9092, rack=null)], clusterId='jKzTkxJYQA-aUaRfyRxMIQ', controllerId=0, topics=[MetadataResponseTopic(errorCode=0, name='quickstart-events', topicId=K7-ZeGbUSZqEyPvZlDbNqg, isInternal=false, partitions=[MetadataResponsePartition(errorCode=0, partitionIndex=0, leaderId=0, leaderEpoch=0, replicaNodes=[0], isrNodes=[0], offlineReplicas=[])], topicAuthorizedOperations=-2147483648)], clusterAuthorizedOperations=-2147483648)
19:08:47.388 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition quickstart-events-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to K7-ZeGbUSZqEyPvZlDbNqg
19:08:47.395 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: jKzTkxJYQA-aUaRfyRxMIQ
19:08:47.396 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Updated cluster metadata updateVersion 2 to MetadataCache{clusterId='jKzTkxJYQA-aUaRfyRxMIQ', nodes={0=il02:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)}, partitions=[PartitionMetadata(error=NONE, partition=quickstart-events-0, leader=Optional[0], leaderEpoch=Optional[0], replicas=0, isr=0, offlineReplicas=)], controller=il02:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)}
19:08:47.399 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received INIT_PRODUCER_ID response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=INIT_PRODUCER_ID, apiVersion=4, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=2): InitProducerIdResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, errorCode=0, producerId=1017, producerEpoch=0)
19:08:47.399 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager - [Producer clientId=producer-1] ProducerId set to 1017 with epoch 0
19:08:47.399 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Transition from state INITIALIZING to READY
19:08:47.414 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
19:08:47.418 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error connecting to node il02:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
java.net.UnknownHostException: il02: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1330)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1283)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1199)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:511)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:468)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:988)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.sendProducerData(Sender.java:354)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:327)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
19:08:47.419 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Beginning shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread, sending remaining records.
19:08:47.465 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error connecting to node il02:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
java.net.UnknownHostException: il02
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1287)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1199)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:511)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:468)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:988)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.sendProducerData(Sender.java:354)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:327)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
19:08:47.474 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
19:08:47.524 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
19:08:47.574 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error connecting to node il02:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
java.net.UnknownHostException: il02
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1287)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1199)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:511)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:468)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:988)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.sendProducerData(Sender.java:354)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:327)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
19:08:47.675 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
19:08:47.726 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
19:08:47.776 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
```

Comment: This might help: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained

Your producer configuration looks right, it's able to connect to the bootstrap server. But then the kafka broker is returning metadata to the client about how to communicate directly with all broker nodes. You might need to configure the `advertised.listeners` in `server.properties` to `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.56.112:9092`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> il02: Name or service not known

That's a DNS error, unrelated to Kafka, and you'd get the same if you tried to ping that hostname...

> I'm using the actual IP when configurin the producer

Then Kafka is defaulting to advertise its own hostname. You can either setup a DNS server that know about your VMs, edit your /etc/hosts with the address for il02 (if you use Vagrant to manage VMs and use host-manager plugin, it'll do that for you), or modify the Kafka server properties so that it advertises its IP instead, but that assumes your VM will always have a static address.

A better option would be to advertise `localhost`, then port forward 9092 through the VM settings, then connect to the `localhost` in your Producer; you may find Docker easier for this rather than a full VM.

Comment: Thanks. It is a DNS issue. I added the entry to the hosts file. I have static IPs setup for my local experimentation VMs.

Comment: Okay, but like I said, a port forward and connecting to `localhost` would be better